# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY -- how to do this on a non primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the the following problem.  I have a table with columns like `id`, `track_id`, `artist_id` and `title`.  The only unique key is the primary key, `id`, which is an auto-increment int.  The `track_id` is not unique.

So the situation arises where I need to update `title` for a record(s) with a specific `track_id`.  If no such record exists, a new one should be created.  I can't use REPLACE INTO or INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY because these operate off of unique or primary keys.  I also cannot use multiple queries because the system this is going into requires these type of actions to be completed in a single query.  That query can be as complicated as necessary, but it all must reside in one query.

How can this be done?

Comment: why not just use a transaction and multiple queries? (unless you're using `MyISAM`)

Comment: The system these are going into exposes wrappers to queries.  These wrappers can only wrap a single query, and chaining the wrapper calls together is not an option.

Comment: my good friend It seems you're fried with this one...

Comment: @Sebas Certainly there is a way to do it.  I've seen far grander acts of magic on SO before than this little old query.

Comment: Can you use a before update trigger?

Comment: If your system can only do 1 query, place the multiple queries inside a stored procedure which your system can call(with one query)

Comment: Can't you create a multi-column UNIQUE key?

Comment: @nos Unfortunately this particular system completely abtracts away mysql.  You populate query templates into flat files which are consumed on initialization.

Comment: Hooray for abstraction layers that make everything "transparent" and prevent people from using long-available and desirable features of relational databases :)

Comment: It sounds like `track_id` should be the primary key! Not being so violates [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) (you effectively have *two* primary keys)

Comment: @Bohemian `track_id` identifies a particular song, which may have been covered by another artists.  So it's possible to have multiple unique rows for such popular songs as Taco's timeless classic "Puttin' on the Ritz."

Comment: Then title is [de-normalized data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalised). You should not store it on the table you have it on and instead just store it on the foreign table and join it when you need it. It would really help if you showed us the schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute these two queries in this order:

```
update track set
title = ?
where track_id = ?;

insert into track (nonkey_col_1, nonkey_col_2, ...)
select 'nonkey_col_1_value',  'nonkey_col_2_value', ...
from track
where not exists (select * from track where track_id = ?)
limit 1;
```

Only one of these will have any effect: The first only executes if there is a row. The second only executes if there *isn't* a row.

Comment: Unfortunately an immutable constraint of my particular environment is that it has to be done in a single query.  The system exposes wrappers, but each wrapper can only contain a single query.  These wrappers are then exposes elsewhere, where it won't be feasible for me to chain them together.

Comment: @kmarks2, the queries don't need to be chained together. If you can't add a compound unique key and use INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE then you can use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to do an upsert. Insert if it does not exist, update if it does. There is no way to do it with android because it does not support multiple queries.

My approach to this kind of things is: first `select track_id from ... where track_id=THE_ID`. If the `resultCursor.getCount()!=0` then the row exists so you need to `update`, else `insert`.

As for the time, a single scalar in the sqlite database is extremely fast.